# Entity Framework Core - orphaned record

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core (7.0.0-rc1-final) in an application that has some tables I do not have control over (they come in from a data feed with orphaned records). Here are some simple models I have created to show this problem:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int BuildingId { get; set; }
    public virtual Building Building { get; set; }
}

public class Building
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to query for the name of the building a person is in and the record has a BuildingId with no record in the Building table that relates it throws an error.

Here is a sample of how I was planning on checking for an orphaned record:

```
var person = _dbContext.Person
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(p => p.Id == personId)
    .Select(p => new
    {
        Name = p.Name,
        HasBuildingName = p.Building == null,
    })
.FirstOrDefault();
```

And here is the exception I get when running the above statement:

> The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types 'System.Int32'
>   and 'System.Object'.

Ideally I would like to run the following code and have "BuildingName" be null if the building id is not found:

```
   var person = _dbContext.Person
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Where(p => p.Id == personId)
        .Select(p => new
        {
            Name = p.Name,
            BuildingName = p.Building == null ? null : p.Building.Name
        })
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Is this an EF bug or is there an alternative way to do this?

EDIT:

For some clarity, this was working perfectly fine until I came across the issue with the orphaned records:

```
var person = _dbContext.Person
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(p => p.Id == personId)
            .Select(p => new
            {
                Name = p.Name,
                BuildingName = p.Building.Name
            })
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: It can be related to the `personId` instead. What is the type of `personId`? Where it come from?

Comment: if I am only retrieving properties from the person object this is working perfectly fine, or if I retrieve p.Building.Name it works perfectly fine when the record is present. This is only an issue when the person has a BuildingId that does not exist in the Building table.

Comment: So do you mean you have broken fk constraints? Or don't have the fk constraint defined in the db? Your buildingid is not null but has a value? This won't work even in previous EF versions.

Comment: Unfortunately we do not control the data and there is no foreign key constraint in the DB and I would like to test for null on the object if it is not found with the Id that exists on the person table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF can't handle a situation where you have a non null Id pointing nowhere as a navigation property. Navigation properties are backed by FKs and optional relations are represented by null Id.

If you don't have fk constraint in your db I would implement both entities as no related and would query them with Join operator instead of navigation properties.

```
var person = _dbContext.Person
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(p => p.Id == personId)
            .GroupJoin(_dbContext.Building, x=>x.BuildingId, x=>X.Id,(p,bs)=> new
            {
                Name = p.Name,
                BuildingName = bs.Select(b=>b.Name).FirstOrDefault()
            })
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Tried this first with a .Join to no avail (it would exclude as an inner join) and then saw that you added the GroupJoin example. This did the trick, but I am not excited about needed to do this on multiple relations. Bad data is never fun :( Thanks for helping me find a possible solution.

Comment: Even though this worked, I ran some performance tests on it and am not going with this solution as it is much quicker to break this up in to 2 queries. This of course will vary for each project and this still answers my initial question. It might be worth adding mention that performance may vary to this answer for people to consider.

Comment: What performance issue did you faced? I would avoid GroupJoin and use regular inner join, that would do it much better, but as your expected result was the person and optional the building I went for GroupJoin

Comment: I basically ran what you provided, but with my actual models multiple times with different input value (values with valid ids and invalid ids). I compared that with breaking it up into a separate query to get the value of the second model with the same values multiple times. This is also on a full test database with real data so it might only be for my scenario.